# Convert CIDR mask to IP mask

Tags: c#, ip, subnet, cidr

What's the easiest way to convert the CIDR subnet mask to the IP mask standard?

Suppose the mask in CIDR is `24`, then I need to get `255.255.255.0`.

Comment: The size is the number of binary 1 at beginning of mask.  So mask is 0xFFFFFF00

Comment: Try following :             int maskSize = 24;
            UInt32 hex = (UInt32)Enumerable.Range(0,maskSize).Sum(x => (1 << (31 - x)));
            string mask = string.Join(".", (hex >> 24).ToString(), ((hex >> 16) & (0xFF)).ToString(), ((hex >> 8) & (0xFF)).ToString(), (hex & (0xFF)).ToString());

Comment: You can also make last line following : string mask = string.Join(".", Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Reverse().Select(x => ((hex >> (8 * x)) & 0xFF).ToString()));

Answer (score 2):

The following code snippet should enable you to easily convert a CIDR notation suffix, such as `/24`, to the equivalent IPv4 bitmask and vice versa.

```cs
public static string CidrToMask(int cidr)
{
    var mask = (cidr == 0)?0:uint.MaxValue << (32 - cidr);
    var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(mask).Reverse().ToArray();
    return new IPAddress(bytes).ToString();
}

public static int MaskToCidr(string subnetMask)
{ 
    var address = IPAddress.Parse(subnetMask);
    var bytes = address.GetAddressBytes();
    var cidr = 0;
    foreach (var t in bytes)
    {
        var b = t;
        while (b > 0)
        {
            cidr++;
            b = (byte)(b << 1);
        }
    } 
    return cidr; 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).